# loop inside another one from different sheets

Tags: vba, loops

I have a problem with my loop.

The task:

look at the first row & column (1,1) of sheet A, if it's not empty, look at first row & column of sheet B, if it's not empty either, sum.

Look at second row (first column) of sheet B, if it's not empty sum with sheet A (1,1) and on...

If sheet B (x,1) is empty, go to sheet A (2,1) and do the same process: A(2,1)+B(1,1) , A(2,1)+B(2,1) , A(2,1)+B(3,1)

If A(x,1) is empty, then exit the macro.

Comment: You should edit your question to add the code from your comment.

Comment: And what's the exact problem with that algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues that you may be experiencing stems from the Do while statements. Try changing them to be.

```
Do While Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1) <> ""
Do While Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 1) <> ""
```

Please word your question to include a clear question somewhere within it. I believe this is what you were asking for but I am not sure.